# C Programming, Errors with Server Socket Calling File From Client

Tags: c, sockets

Hello StackOverflow Subscribers, I am having Some issues with reading the server socket data into a buffer in order to retrieve a File From the Client. I Believe it is the way its called I don't Think the entire string is written into the variable before it tries to call the file! perror returns no such file or directory!

IM very new to C programming and realize its very literal with some things...

So What I'm asking is if someone could help me figure out how to send the filename via socket to the client and have the client fetch me a file!

If it could be a simple fix that would be awesome because I'm new to C and I've been doing this program for about 3 days and don't wanna redo the whole code.... Thanks in Advance for any help!! Heres the part of the code I'm having issues with!!

```
                if (fgets(dataRead, sizeof(buffer), fp) !=NULL){
                    fputs(buffer, stdout);
                    perror("fputs");

                    perror("fgets");
                    printf("this is buffer : %s", buffer);




                FILE *dl = fopen(buffer, "r"); //THIS IS THE BUG!
                perror("dl");



                if (dl == NULL){
                    printf("failed to open file");

                }else{

                    while ( (c = fgetc(dl)) !=EOF){

                        fprintf(fp,"%c",c);
                        perror("fprintf");
                        fflush(fp);
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is supposed to work? Is the end of the file name marked with a newline character in the byte stream? Or is it marked some other way? What *precisely* is `buffer`? Is it a pointer? An array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the newline from 'buffer' like below

```
if (fgets(dataRead, sizeof(buffer), fp) !=NULL){
                    strtok(buffer, "\n"); //this removes the newline
                    fputs(buffer, stdout);
                    perror("fputs");
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: That Definitely Worked! Thank You Very Much.... So when I was Trying to send  the filename  a newline was inserted and thats why i was getting the error file not found.. (DUH)  I dont know how many times i changed the code trying different things and its always something simple thanks Thiru Shetty Youve saved me loads of trouble!!

Answer (score 0):

fopen with "r" means opening a file in read-only mode this expects file to be present at the specified path.

are you sure that buffer contains exactly the file you want to open ?
and that file exists at the give path relative to your executable.

```
FILE *dl = fopen(buffer, "r");
```

Tip almost always use quotes while printing variables it'll help identifying trailing spaces like this.

```
printf("this is buffer : '%s' ", buffer);
```